# Sony WF-1000xm4 with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS issues

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, headphones

I've been using my Sony WF-1000xm4 with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

After recent updates and reboot connection became unstable with constant lags and hiccups.

Reinstalled bluez. Now headphones only sort of "pair' - they are visible in the devices list, but do not connect. The slider in the connect window just immediately goes back.

Tried resetting bluetooth on Ubuntu and the headphones as well.

It also 'pairs' with LE_WF-1000XM4, but with no confirmation from the headphones and output.

sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service output is:

Mar 28 09:57:16 pcname bluetoothd[5843]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for //some mac address: Protocol not available

// turns out there was no pulse-audio.

Installed it, but it changed nothing

pulseaudio-module-bluetooth/jammy-updates,now 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]

Answer (score 0):

This particular earphone only can be connected in pairing mode. Seems to be an "LE" issue with the linux bluetooth stack. Same with the older Sony WF-1000XM3. Tap and hold both earphones for 7 sec. Wait for the corresponding audio message. Try again connecting. It will show "WF-1000XM4" first, will connect, and show "LE_WF-1000XM4" as "headphone" device instead of "unknown" afterwards. And then this can be used as both audio device and microphone. If you happen to see "LE_WF-1000XM4" first, wait until you see "WF-1000XM4", do **not** choose the LE device.